# How to unlist spatial objects and plot altogether in R

Tags: r, list, geospatial, spatial

I have spatial lines as 'list':

```
> SL1
[[1]]
class       : SpatialLines 
nfeatures   : 1 
extent      : 253641, 268641, 2621722, 2621722  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

[[2]]
class       : SpatialLines 
nfeatures   : 1 
extent      : 253641, 268641, 2622722, 2622722  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

[[3]]
class       : SpatialLines 
nfeatures   : 1 
extent      : 253641, 268641, 2623722, 2623722  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 ... ...
```

When I want to plot a single line, I can plot it as

```
plot(SL1[[1]])
```

But if I want to plot all the lines together, R throws an error:

```
> plot(SL1)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

I know I have to unlist, but it remains the same after I write:

```
SL1<-unlist(SL1)
```

Any solution??

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `lapply(SL1, plot)`, or perhaps `lapply(SL1, function(x) plot(x, add=TRUE))`? At the moment all you deserve are guesses since you have provided no test data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put them all into one `SpatialLines` object. To do this you need to extract the `Lines` objects from each SpatialLines item in your list, then you can extract the individual `lines` objects from this, then you can use this list to recombine them into a single SpatialLines object:

```
#  Get the Lines objects which contain multiple 'lines'
ll0 <- lapply( SL1 , function(x) `@`(x , "lines") )

#  Extract the individual 'lines'
ll1 <- lapply( unlist( ll0 ) , function(y) `@`(y,"Lines") )

#  Combine them into a single SpatialLines object
Sl <- SpatialLines( list( Lines( unlist( ll1 ) , ID = 1 ) ) )
```

S4 classes!